# How can I save a url hash to a variable for use on a different page with a different url?

Tags: jquery, api, instagram

I am using the instagram api and I registered and got passed the authorization. It returns  an access token in the url hash, since I am using "Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication."

> http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=20001105.f59def8.a85e3ca34d8b406f9c0ec54a44d0bcf5

I save the access token hash as a variable and add it to the ajax json url like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?" + hash,
```

I want to save the hash to a variable I can access later on a different page, so that it's not in the url bar.

How can this be done with using PHP or javascript and jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

To save it on the browser, you would either save it to a cookie or to local storage (newer browsers only).

You will be limited to only access the data from the same domain that you originally stored it from, but as long as the multiple pages that want access to this saved data are on the same domain, you can store it this way.  This is, in fact, how most sites do a client-login and then remember that login state from one page to the next (generally using cookies).

Comment: Ok thank you. I didn't even think about html5 and localstorage. I'll try to figure that out, since i plan on this being a mobile web app.

Comment: new problem. localstorage doesnt work on localhost. It's saving the key but not the value. I don't have a server or anyway to setup a server. Im using MAMP pro to test with. Any ideas to get localstorage to work?